# How to properly use Parse.query.equalTo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

In my web application when the user logs in they should see all the documents they made. However when I test my application, I see all the documents including the ones that I didn't make. I believe this is because I am not using Parse.query.equalTo correctly.

Here is my code:

```
    router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var tempname = req.body.username;
    var username = tempname.toLowerCase();
    var password = req.body.password;
    var login = Promise.promisify(Parse.User.logIn);
    var promerror = Promise.reject("error");
    var Files = Parse.Object.extend("File");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Files);
    query.include('user');
    var finds = query.find;
    var doc = {};
    var name, url;
    return login(username, password).catch(function (error) {
    }).then(function (user, error) {
        query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
        console.log(JSON.stringify(Parse.User.current()));
        if (user) {
            res.render('logins', { Message: "Username and/or password don't match" });
        }
        var temp;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.render('logins');
    }).then(query.find(function (results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            var userID = object.get('user');
            console.log("current user");
            var codefile = object.get('javaFile');
            temp = codefile.name();
            name = temp.split("-").pop();
            url = codefile.url();
            doc[name] = url;
        }
    })).catch(function (error) {
        promerror(error);
    }).finally(function () {
        res.render('filename', { title: 'File Name', FIles: JSON.stringify(doc) });
    }).done();
});
```

When the user logs in, it should go to the database retrieve all the documents the user made, and save it to `doc`, the `doc` is then send to the client side to be displayed.

here is the code for user saving a file:

```
 newFile.save({ user: Parse.User.current(), fileName: newnames, javaFile: parseFile })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try setting the File user field to the object id instead of the user object itself. Parse objects sometimes will return a pointer, sometimes the id, etc. So you might be getting unexpected behavior where you're setting the field to `Parse.User.current()`. Besides that, you look like you're using equalTo correctly.

Otherwise, basically the only way to debug cloud code is to console.log and view the logs.

As a side note, you should be setting the ACL of each File before you save it... that way, a user wouldn't be able to view another user's files anyway (unless these files are meant to be public).